# I need to setup a icon menu for my aplication

Tags: java, java-me, icons, midlet

How can I setup an icon in my j2me aplication ? I have setup this icon in my midlet configuration, but I can see in mobile menu. Where Should I put my icon ?

Comment: Please fix your question: I guess you mean an "application icon" to show up in the application menu of your mobile, not an "icon menu", right? Also, probably you **can't** (not *can*) see the icon in the application menu, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Application icon should be placed in application descriptor (manifest.mf or JAD file) as:

```
MIDlet-Icon: myicon.png
```

Comment: ok, but where should be the image? in 'res'? over 'res'? I can't see this icon, thanks

Comment: neither "res" not over "res". It's by default in "resources" directory